# Python: Opposite number performance comparison

Tags: python-3.x, performance

Why is

```
def opposite(number):
    number - number*2
```

returning a faster result than

```
def opposite(number):
    return -number
```

in python?

Answer (score 1):

[time by method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QehkG.png)

Here you can see the difference of performance of the two methods

```
def opposite(number): 
 
    number - number*2
```

```
def opposite2(number):

    return -number
```

```
%timeit opposite(5)
84.3 ns ± 2.33 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%timeit opposite2(5)
66.5 ns ± 6.88 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```